# A generator that counts to infinity

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just for fun and out of curiosity, I devised this way of writing a generator that counts to infinity, at least in principle. Nothing very pythonian. Just playing around.

But obviously with each iteration `lis` gets longer until something will eventually break.

Are there other (better or worse) ways to achieve the same goal? Please share.

```
lis = [1]
gen = ((k, lis.append(k+1))[0] for k in lis)
```

To use it

```
for j in gen:
    print(j)
```

Comment: `for i in itertools.count(1): print(i)`... ? See [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) which also contains equivalent Python code...

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 not sure that's the best dupe target (I was looking for one) - as it focuses mostly on an infinitely repeating sequence (although one answer does briefly mention `itertools.count`) - not an infinitely incrementing sequence...

Comment: Why even use a generator if you are going to be holding a list in memory?

Comment: @JonClements - The question just asks for "infinite elements," and `itertools.count()` is the first suggestion in the highest-voted answer. It's not 100% focused on only incrementing sequences to the total exclusion of a static cycle, but I don't think that's a flaw.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 quoting the OP: *I devised this way of writing a generator that counts to infinity* [...] *Are there other (better or worse) ways to achieve the same goal?* I'm taking **count** to be distinct from *infinite iterable*.

Comment: @JonClements - I meant the question in the linked dup. It just asks for "infinite elements." It's a little more broad than this question's infinite increment, but it includes an answer that mentions `itertools.count()`. The castle is a little bigger, but it holds the right answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.count(1):
    print(i)
```

From the docs above this is functionally equivalent to:

```
def count(start=0, step=1):
    # count(10) --> 10 11 12 13 14 ...
    # count(2.5, 0.5) -> 2.5 3.0 3.5 ...
    n = start
    while True:
        yield n
        n += step
```

You can use it like this:

```
>>> my_generator = count(3, 2)
>>> next(my_generator)
3
>>> next(my_generator)
5
>>> next(my_generator)
7
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.count). Here's an example:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> gen = count(0)
>>> next(gen)
0
>>> next(gen)
1
>>> next(gen)
2
>>> next(gen)
3
>>> next(gen)
4
>>>
```